# How can I compare a variable to a number in an if statement using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried to make an if statement to check if a variable is 2. But everytime I try, I get the else statement. 
Here's my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').html(2);
    var antkeepere = document.getElementById('test');

    if(antkeepere==2){
        $('#mer').html('Ja!')
    } 
    else{
        $('#mer').html('Nei!')
    };
});
```

First I wrote 2 in my html, but it didn't work. THen I tried to make it 2 through js as in the example over, but it didn't work either. I have searched through other threads like this and tried to but .value both in the if statement and when creating the variabel, but none of them worked either.

Comment: You are comparing a `DOM` object with a number. They are different

Comment: as method suggest document.getElementById() give me element in document with that id and not its content. So you are comparing element with 2. Get the content and compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` returns the DOM element, not its contents. To get its HTML content, you have to use the `.innerHTML` property. And to convert it to a number, you should use `parseInt()`.

```
var antkeepere = parseInt(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML, 10);
```

Since you're using jQuery, you can stick with that:

```
var antkeepere = parseInt($("#test").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

because `document.getElementById('test');` returns a dom object.

try this

```
var antkeepere = $("#test").val();
```

Comment: He is saying using Java Script and you gave him jQuery solution

Comment: @ShoaibChikate The OP is also using jQuery.

Comment: he used `$('#test').html(2);`

Answer (score 0):

You do like this in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').html(2);
    var antkeepere =$('test').html();

    if(parseInt(antkeepere) == 2){
        $('#mer').html('Ja!')
    } 
    else{
        $('#mer').html('Nei!')
    };
});
```

Since you are putting the 2 using .html `$('#test').html(2);` you can also access that using the same function `.html()` but without the arguments.

If comparing the `antkeepere` variable to 2 you need to parse it so it's will convert it into a number because `.html` returns a string.
so that is why you need to do this `if(parseInt(antkeepere) == 2)`

If you are going to compare string you don't need to `parseInt` you can simply go like this  `if(antkeepere == 'aaab')`

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not retrieving the html of `#test` but the whole element. Second, to make sure the html value is a *number* with value 2, you should try to convert the html value to a `Number`. A simple code adjustment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').html(2);
    var antkeepere = Number(document.getElementById('test').html());

    if(antkeepere === 2){
        $('#mer').html('Ja!')
    } 
    else{
        $('#mer').html('Nei!')
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 //As I understand test is div or span not input type objects. if it is input type element then use val() instead of html()

 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#test').html(2);
     var antkeepere = document.getElementById('test');
    //   use can also use parseInt($('#test').html())
    if(parseInt(antkeepere.innerHTML)==2){
       $('#mer').html('Ja!')
     } 
     else{
       $('#mer').html('Nei!')
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers above are pretty good, but seeing as you've already loaded jQuery, you may as well use it (you don't need document.getElement...).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').text(2); // Using text() instead of html() just means you can write stuff like "&", instead of "&amp;"
    var antkeepere = parseFloat( $('#test').text() ); // parseFloat ensures the contents of test is converted to a number.

    if(antkeepere == 2){
        $('#mer').text('Ja!')
    } 
    else{
        $('#mer').text('Nei!')
    };
});
```